# Can we still post to facebook wall in Facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: objective-c, facebook, xcode4.5

The post in scrumptuous posts post to me/fb_sample_scrumps:eat

What about if I want to post to wall instead of to me/fb_sample_scrupts:eat?

Also why I have to create action first?

What about if I just want to post "Hello World" or something?

Also is there a way to post without the user have to keep being asked what to post? For example, I want to post, "First Name like Kentucky Fried Chicken" when user press like on Kentucky Fried Chicken.

Comment: When you say "3.1", what exactly are you talking about ?

Comment: I've been looking for ways to post to the wall, i mean post message, not some graph action, to the wall, I couldn't find it. There are sample code on how to do so with facebook sdk 3.0. None for 3.1